# Grant read permission on List for Anonymous user for public facing site in Sharepoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a public facing SP site ( SP online 2013 with Office 365 ). There are certain app parts added to it which read data from a custom list created on that site. By default anonymous users do not have read permissions list. I want users to see the list data without login in . I tried modifying the settings for anonymous users , however I am unable to do it as the "anonymous user" permissions cannot be checked by me.
[image]

How do I provide read permissions to anonymous users?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If i remember rightly enabled anonymous access on the list simply allows users who aren't authenticated to view the list.  However they won't be able to access the list directly on the interface as you would need to be authenticated for that.  If the list is accessed directly from a web part or user control then you simply need to ensure the page which contains the control is published and your site available as anonymous access.